# Delete node from singly linked list and do an operation on it

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I am tasked with removing a node from a singly linked list and setting the structure that the node's dataPtr points to, to a new value. I create a structure pointer to hold the data of the popped node. There are 2 cases I want to catch 1) in which this new pointer is null, I want to set it to the popped node 2) if the pointer is not null, I want to do some operations on it.

```
NODE* printer;
printer = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof (NODE));   //dynamically allocate
if(printer==NULL){                  //if it has no data
    printer= deleteNode(sList);     //call deleteNode function which returns popped node from the passed singly linked list   
} else if (printer!=NULL && sList->count!=0) {       //if it has data
    (((PRINTJOB *) printer->dataPtr)->pageNums) -= PAGESPERMINUTE;    //decrement the pageNums field by 1 (PAGESPERMINUTE)
    if ((((PRINTJOB *) printer->dataPtr)->pageNums) <= 0) {      //if the field is less than 0
        printer = NULL;   //set pointer back to null
    }
    printf("printers pageNum is: %d\n", ((PRINTJOB *) printer->dataPtr)->pageNums);
}
```

My compiler is giving me an error on 4th line: *The value is never used.*
It is also giving me an error in my else if statement: *first condition is always true.*
When I run this code block as well, it crashes my program.

My deleteNode function is:

```
#include "headers.h"
void* deleteNode(LIST* list){
    NODE *toDelete;
    toDelete = list->head;
    list->head = toDelete->next;
    return toDelete;
}
```

my NODE structure is:

```
typedef struct node{ 
    void* dataPtr;
    struct node* next;
} NODE;
```

Comment: you don't need to test `printer!=NULL`, it will only get to that else if it happens to be NULL

Comment: The code does not make much sense.  You are allocating uninitialized memory for a new node.  If the allocation fails, you then invoke the `deleteNode` function to pop the front item off your list.  If allocation is successful, you start trying to access stuff in this uninitialized node, which will result in undefined behavior.  If by some pure chance this doesn't crash, there's a chance you'll end up setting the pointer to NULL which leaks memory, and then your `printf` call will crash after you do a NULL dereference.

Comment: your delete function has a bug, you are not changing the head of the list when you return from the function

Comment: what is the bug in my delete function?

Comment: pass it as `(LIST **list)` and wherever you are use list, dereference it... and where you are calling it, add a &

Comment: @vmp that is unnecessary.  It's fine to pass the list as a pointer.  That is not a bug.  If anything, the OP should be encouraged to _simplify_ their use of pointers because they are clearly having difficulty understanding how to use them.

Comment: The bug happens when he does `list->head = toDelete->next;`... The parameter that he passed to this function won't be changed by doing that

Comment: Um... They are not trying to modify the `list` pointer back at the call site.  `list->head` _will_ be changed.  I repeat.  This is not a bug.  It seems that you might be also misunderstanding pointers here.  If anything, the only bug I can see in `deleteNode` is that it does not update `list->count`, which according to usage in another example is a data member of `LIST` and should contain a count of how many nodes are in the list.  But that's not why the program is crashing.  See my very first comment.

Comment: No I'm not misunderstanding... I just don't know if this is the only bug since I don't have access to all the code and don't know what he is trying to do

Comment: @paddy check the code I posted, execute it and tell me where is my misunderstanding please

Comment: @vmp You have failed to understand that they obviously have a separate "list" structure that contains a head-pointer.  And so you've then assumed that type `LIST` is the same as type `NODE`, despite them showing the definition of `NODE` which does _not_ contain a member named `head` (or `count`).

Comment: I didn't fail to understand. He failed to provide enough information. He is calling delete first, the checking on the count happens in the else. I'm just spotting a possible bug in a small part of the code that seemed understandable.

Comment: @vmp I'm going to stop responding now.  You _still_ don't seem to understand what either me or John Bollinger is saying.

Comment: I saw your point now, sorry. Only slept for 3 hours in the last 2 days, good night!

Answer (score 1):

> I am tasked with removing a node from a singly linked list and setting the structure that the node's dataPtr points to, to a new value.

But you remove the node only conditionally (and on a condition that is unlikely to actually occur).  If, as stated, the first step is to remove a node then Remove. That. Node.

> I create a structure pointer to hold the data of the popped node.

But you shouldn't.  If there is any data available to receive then that's because a node containing it already exists, and your `deleteNode()` function will return a pointer to it (provided that function is in fact called).

> There are 2 cases I want to catch 1) in which this new pointer is null, I want to set it to the popped node

That makes no sense, because it makes no sense to create a new, separate node in the first place.  What *would* make sense would be to check whether `deleteNode` returns a null pointer, which one imagines it might do if the list were empty (but see below).

> 2. if the pointer is not null, I want to do some operations on it.

That could make sense, but not in this context.  According to your description, you want to perform operations on the node that was removed from the list (provided that one in fact was removed), but instead you are working on the newly-allocated, uninitialized node.

Based only on your description of the task itself, it sounds like you want something more like this:

```
NODE* printer = deleteNode(sList);
if (printer != NULL) {
    (((PRINTJOB *) printer->dataPtr)->pageNums) -= PAGESPERMINUTE;    
    if ((((PRINTJOB *) printer->dataPtr)->pageNums) <= 0) {
        printer = NULL;   //set pointer back to null (?)
    }
    printf("printers pageNum is: %d\n", ((PRINTJOB *) printer->dataPtr)->pageNums);
} // else nothing to do
```

But **there are other possibilities**, depending on how the list is structured and used.

Note that the `printer = NULL;` line that I copied from your original code is questionable.  It may make sense if later code performs a null check on `printer` before doing yet more processing, and you want to circumvent that.  Beware, however, that failing to first `free()` the node might constitute a memory leak.  It looks suspicious in that way, but it is possible that the node really shouldn't be freed there.

Note also, however, that your `deleteNode()` function appears to be likely  to break when it operates on an empty list.  In that event, it seems like the only sensible thing it could return is a null pointer.  It might well be that `list->head` is in fact such a pointer in that case, but then

> ```
>     NODE *toDelete;
>     toDelete = list->head;
>     list->head = toDelete->next;
> ```

will attempt to dereference that null pointer when it evaluates `toDelete->next`, thus reaping undefined behavior.  If in fact you can rely on `list->head` to be null when the list is empty, then you would want to modify the above something like this:

```
    NODE *toDelete;
    toDelete = list->head;
    if (toDelete != NULL) {
        list->head = toDelete->next;
    } // else list->head is already NULL
```

Again, there are other possibilities depending on how the list is structured and used, but I think the above is probably what you want.